Can MinGW's static library be linked to MSVC
I use mingw-w64 on linux to cross compile the ffmpeg static library for windows with the following command:
./configure --arch=x86 --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffmpeg --prefix=/mnt/c/ffmpeg --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --pkg-config=pkg-config --disable-shared --enable-static

make -j16
make install

Then I got some .a files instead of .lib files. Can I directly link these files to MSVC? If not, what should I do next?

In general you can't. Sometimes the opposite (compiling on MSVC, using with MinGW) works for some C libraries, so maybe what you're saying can work too. But why you don't just use one compiler all the way? Either use MinGW on Windows too, or use MSVC on Linux (this might get complicated).

@HolyBlackCat I want to compile ffmpeg library for windows on wsl, I try to use --toolchain=msvc, but this doesn't work. Maybe I should compile it into a dynamic library?

Why are you using wsl instead of compiling directly on Windows?

I would recommend installing it through vcpkg, if your compiler of choice is MSVC.

@HolyBlackCat How do I run configure on windows? Using msys2 should give the same result. Vcpkg is a good choice, but for learning purposes I just want to compile it myself following the guide. Generating .a files instead of .lib files frustrated me and I don't know what to do next

"How do I run configure on windows?" MSYS2 includes bash which can run it. FFmpeg have a guide for compiling for MSVC, but that uses MSYS1 rather than MSYS2. Adapting it to MSYS2 should be simple though, run VS developer command prompt, from it run MSYS shell (c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -full-path), then ./configure --toolchain=msvc && make. I'll try it myself in a moment.

@HolyBlackCat I've been using wsl for a long time, so I didn't want to install msys at first. I could only find tutorials for cross-compile dynamic libraries in the browser instead of static libraries, so I tried to follow ffmpeg's CrossCompilingForWindows guide to compile static libraries, but I didn't get .lib files. I know that dynamic libraries can be linked to MSVC and static libraries can't, but I gave a glimmer of hope that maybe the cross-compile static libraries are a little different

I compiled a working dynamic library on wsl, I just want to know if there is a way to compile a working static library on it

Perhaps just renaming .lib to .a will work? Google says both are AR archives.

But the idea itself (compiling with MinGW, then using the library with MSVC) seems sketchy, even for shared libraries. While pure C libraries are supposed to be compatible across compilers, MinGW is likely to use a different C runtime (though there are versions that use the same C runtime as the modern MSVC). This post says it's ok if you're careful, but I'd rather not.

If you insist on cross-compiling from Linux and insist on using MSVC on Windows rather than MSVC, the best option IMO is to use clang-cl on Linux to produce MSVC-compatible libs (point it to the MSVC installation from https://github.com/mstorsjo/msvc-wine)

@HolyBlackCat Renaming .a to .lib doesn't work. And you're right, using the dynamic library does require some different C runtime in my case

Even though you asked for a cross-compilation, here's how you do it natively on Windows. I'd rather do this than trying to use MinGW libraries with MSVC.
This is adapted to MSYS2 from the official guide that uses MSYS1.

Install MSYS2 from https://www.msys2.org/
Update it using pacman -Syu. If it closes itself during update, restart and run pacman -Syu to finish the update.
Install things the ./configure script asks for: pacman -S make diffutils mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-yasm.
Close MSYS2, open VS developer command prompt, start MSYS2 inside of it using C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -ucrt64 -full-path. This will add cl.exe to the PATH.
cd to FFmpeg source directory, ./configure --toolchain=msvc, make -j4, DESTDIR="$(realpath inst)" make install to install to ./inst.


I successfully built the dynamic library in wsl using --toolchain=msvc. Modify configure to use the wslpath command so that CC_DEPCMD use the wsl path instead of the Windows path. Then most importantly, execute the wsl command in cmd instead of the shell. Other than that, this looks the same as using cl.exe compile in MSYS

I would strongly advise to not mix different build tools.
Why would you cross-compile ffmpeg to then link with it with MSVC?
Much better would be to stick with one build environment (MSVC in your case) to build everything.
It is possible to build ffmpeg with MSVC according to: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC
